# Package Name of Ubuntu Installer

Tags: system-installation

Does anybody know what the 'Package Name' of the Ubuntu Installer is? The Ubuntu bug reporting engine (bugs.launchpad.net) asks for a package but the search engine does not return anything for the query `ubuntu installer`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default desktop installer is `ubiquity`.

https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Ubiquity

Answer (score 3):

If you do not know the open package's name, you can file a bug against the open window.

In your terminal, enter:

```
ubuntu-bug -w
```

It pops up a window with directions, it looks like this:

[image: filing a bug against an open window]

So, you'd basically make sure the installer is still open (or open it again) and then open the terminal, run this prompt, click on close, and then click on the installer window. From there, you just follow the prompts in the terminal to file the bug.

You can learn more about bug reporting [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs).